# Brake pad and caliper seizing

Tags: brakes, nissan, murano, seizing

I changed my brake pad,caliper and rotor for all 4. its a 2004 Nissan Murano.

After that, when I am driving inside the city for an hour or so and perform frequent braking, the front right side brake will heat up.  When I stop at a signal and then accelerate, it will make noise as if its stuck.

Comment: Is there any more information you can add to the post?  How do you know it's hotting?  How did you measure the temp?  Thanks for contributing to the site and welcome.  Cheers!

Comment: Sounds to me like the flex line is swelling up.

Comment: Also, after you start up, if you put the car in neutral and let it coast, does it not coast as far as it feels like it should? I would also try putting a jack under the front of the car, and seeing if there is a rolling resistance difference between the left and right sides. Just spin the wheel with your hand at roughly the same force, and see how long it continues to turn. If one is just harder to turn than the other, something is binding that wheel.. Could be caliper stuck, pad stuck, etc...